# Multiple preposition in a sentence

Tags: verbs, prepositions, sentence, syntactic-analysis

I would like to use both ***insert*** and ***remove*** in the same sentence. However, I would like to know how I will use the prepositions because the verbs have different prepositions ***into/from***.

There are some posts about this issue; however, mine is a little bit different because there is an object after my verbs as seen below.

> This method either inserts or removes some parameters from queries.

What is the correct way of writing this sentence? I am not sure because both **insert** and ***remove*** needs ***some parameters***.

> This method either inserts into or removes some parameters from queries.

I think the above does not sound well,

or

> This method either inserts or removes some parameters into or from queries.

Thanks

Comment: By this method, parameters are either added to or removed from queries.